# Why Jquery "this" is not working as expected?

Tags: jquery, this

I have below html code

```
<button id="b">
    Test
</button>
```

and javascript code

```
$("#b").click(function(){
    var name = "test button";
    console.log($(this).name);
});
```

, but when i click on the button , name variable is not printing on the console

Comment: what is the expected value?

Comment: You can directly use `this.name` it will work !!!

Comment: Here name is just a local variable that is not button name.To assign name for button you can use `this.name="test button"`

Comment: What is the use of printing the name of the button when you don't assign it? `name` is local to the click function and not attached to `$(this)` so just `console.log(name)` to print it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use:

```
console.log(name);
```

since `name` is a variable here.

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wqzD7/)**

if you want to get the `id` value of the button then use:

```
console.log(this.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your function, the variable `name` is just a local variable.  it isn't a property of any object so when you do `$(this).name` it isn't a property of that jQuery object.

If you want to just log the local variable to the console, you would just use:

```
console.log(name);
```

If you wanted to assign it to be a property of your object, then you would not make a local variable, but would do this instead:

```
$("#b").click(function(){
    this.name = "test button";
    console.log(this.name);
});
```

If you want to actually change the text of the button, then you would do this:

```
$("#b").click(function(){
    this.innerHTML = "test button";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have:

```
<button id="b" name="test">
    Test
</button>
```

then:

```
$("#b").click(function(){

    console.log($(this).attr("name"));
});
```

if you want get variable value, then you don't need to use `this`

then simply do this:

```
$("#b").click(function(){
    var name = "test button";
    console.log(name);
});
```

[**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/3eYmp/)

Answer (score 0):

$(this) refers to Object , as you can see there is no name property in that object
Try to debug

```
console.log(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are in a different scope. `this` refers to the button, not to the just created var. See following examples:

```
// First we provide a button
<button id="lala">Click</button>
```

Some Javascript will follow:

```
function myObject() {
    this.hello = 'hello';
};

var myObject2 = (function () {
    var hello = 'hello';

    function getHello() {
        return hello;
    };

    return {
        getHello: getHello
    };
})();

// In your case
$('#lala').on('click', function () {
    this.hello = 'hello';

    console.log("I'm a property of the current 'this' : " + this.hello);
    console.log("I'm sent by the button, so in this case I'm the button : ");
    console.log(this);

    // Now lets see what happens if we log the 2 objects
    console.log(myObject.hello);

    var instanceOfObject = new myObject();

    console.log("Now I show you the 'hello'! : " + instanceOfObject.hello);

    // This will not work because it's the revealing module pattern(you can work a kind of with getters and setters). Directly calling 'hello' will not work(it's kind of private).
    console.log(myObject2.hello);

    console.log("Greetings from myObject2 : " + myObject2.getHello());
});
```

The fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/3WE6W/

If you want to learn more about javascript and the populair `Revealing module pattern`(like myObject2) read this article: http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/